# How to create a Scramble function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm am trying to create a simple slider game using javascript. It's i simple 4 by 4 number slider game with each button being labeled 1-15 with the last block being a blank block. I just have no idea on how to scramble the buttons in a random order to start the game.

Below is the code I currently have.

```
   <body>

   <h1> Slider Game </h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       var blankrow = 3;
       var blankcol = 3;

       for (var r=0; r<4; r++)
       {
           for (var c=0; c<4; c++)
           {
               var bid = "b"+r+c;
               var val = 4*r+c+1;
               if (bid==="b33")
                   val = ' ';
               var s = '<input type = "button" id = "' + bid + '" value = "' 
                        + val + '" onclick = "makeMove(this.id);" />' + '\n';
               document.write (s);
           }
       }
    </script>

    <input type = "button" id = "btnScramble" value = "Scramble" onclick = "scrambleBoard();"/>
    <input type = "button" id = "btnReset" value = "Reset Board" onclick = "resetBoard();"/>


</body>
```

I created a function like this:

```
function scrambleBoard()
             {


             }
```

I just have no idea where to go from here. I am just learning Javascript so I am still learning how to code. Thanks!

Update:

This is the make move function I have

```
 function makeMove(btnid)
             {
                //is btnid next to blank  
                var r = btnid.substr(1,1);
                var c = btnid.substr(2,2);

        if (blankrow==r && blankcol==c+1) // check right
                {
                   blankid="b"+r+c;
                   document.getElementById(blankid).value = document.getElementById(btnid).value;
                   document.getElementById(btnid).value = ' ';
                   blankcol=c;
                }
                else if (blankrow==r && blankcol==c-1) // check left
                {
                   blankid="b"+r+c;
                   document.getElementById(blankid).value = document.getElementById(btnid).value;
                   document.getElementById(btnid).value = ' ';
                   blankcol=c;
                } 
                else if (blankrow==r+1 && blankcol==c) // check bottem
                {
                   blankid="b"+r+c;
                   document.getElementById(blankid).value = document.getElementById(btnid).value;
                   document.getElementById(btnid).value = ' ';
                   blankrow=r;
                } 
                else if (blankrow==r-1 && blankcol==c) // check top
                {
                   blankid="b"+r+c;
                   document.getElementById(blankid).value = document.getElementById(btnid).value;
                   document.getElementById(btnid).value = ' ';
                   blankrow=r;
                } else
                   alert("Move is invalid");

             }
```

Now with this how would I take the function (makeMove) and put it into the scramble function. Sorry I am really having a hard time understanding this concept.

Comment: Create an array holding the numbers from 1 to 15, shuffle it – and then take one value after another out of that shuffled array. (Shuffling an array is something you can easily research.)

Comment: The [15-puzzle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/15Puzzle.html) (as this is known) has one interesting property: it has two different domains (or 'alternating groups'); *only one* of the groups can be solved, and the other can never be solved. To generate a board one 'well known approach' is to randomize (with a shuffle) *all the tiles* and then if in the 'unsolvable' state, simply switch two adjacent tiles (and the puzzle will be in a solvable state).

Comment: @CBroe By itself a shuffle will yield an unsolvable board half the time.

Comment: @user2864740: Thanks, I didn’t take into account that the game might have additional requirements. Now all that’s left to figure out for OP is how to test for “unsolvable state”, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a `makeMove` function that fills the hole from a selected direction anyway, in order to make the game. Scramble is very simple: repeat the `makeMove` operation a sufficient number of times with a random neighbour (ignoring invalid neighbours like sliding from left at the left edge).

EDIT: Style-wise, `document.write` is considered to be a bad practice. Much better would be to make an element such as

```
<div id="board"></div>
```

and then fill it up by either creating documents with `document.createElement` and adding it there, which is a bit of a pain, or you can go the easy route and assign HTML markup to `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('board').innerHTML = allMyButtonsHTML;
```

Also, using `onclick="..."` is considered a bad practice; try to get used to not mixing JavaScript and HTML by simply leaving off the `onclick="..."`, and instead assigning it from JavaScript:

```
var scrambleButton = document.getElementById('btnScramble');
scrambleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ...
});
```

None of this is an error as it stands, but it will result in cleaner, more maintainable code in the future.

EDIT2: You would not be putting `makeMove` into the shuffle, you'd be calling it from there.

```
function shuffleBoard() {
  // the hole starts here
  var holeRow = 3, holeCol = 3;
  // the number of shuffling moves
  var moves = 100;
  // repeat while moves is not yet at zero
  loop: while (moves) {
    // we want to move one space from our current hole, so start there
    var nextRow = holeRow, nextCol = holeCol;
    // get a random number from 0 to 3 using the |0 hack
    // to convert a real number to an integer
    var direction = (Math.random() * 4)|0;
    // now to see what coordinate changes...
    switch (direction) {
      case 0:
        // if we're going right, we increment the column
        // if that puts us too far right, we jump to the start of the loop
        // to pick a new direction again
        if (nextCol++ > 3) continue loop;
        break;
      case 1:
        // same deal for down
        if (nextRow++ > 3) continue loop;
        break;
      case 2:
        // and left
        if (nextCol-- < 0) continue loop;
        break;
      case 3:
        // and up
        if (nextRow-- > 0) continue loop;
        break;
    }
    // this should be more elegant but
    // like this it will fit in with your existing function
    makeMove('b' + nextRow + nextCol);
    // now since we moved the hole, we update its current position
    holeRow = nextRow;
    holeCol = nextCol;
    // that's one move down, lots to go!
    moves--;
  }
  // or is it? nope, all done.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add the first button, loop through however many more you need to create. Use math.random to pick a random number 0-1. If the number is 0, use insertadjacenthtml to add a new button to the left. If the number is 1, add the button to the right.

Comment: This can result in an unsolvable puzzle.